# How do I pass PHP parameters through an sprintf() to a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, php, parameters, onclick, printf

I have been charged with taking over a project to develop a web tool/interface for a proprietary bit of software. The current sticking point is (using the established practices / patterns) to perform a connection test to the server based upon values entered by the user.

Currently, there is a sub-menu formatted with an sprintf().  I have attempted various methods to pass the parameters, but the receiving JavaScript funciton fails.

The submenu:

```
$submenu = sprintf('<div id="Menu"><ul id="ControlSubMenu">%s</ul></div>',
                '<li><a href="#inner_content" class="TestConn" id="TestConn" onClick="testpbxconnection($ct_host, $ct_port, $ct_un, $ct_pw);return false;">Test Connection</a></li>
 <li> <a href="#inner_content" class="EditConn" id="EditConn" onClick="editpbxconnection();return false;">Edit Connection</a></li>');
```

The receiving JS function, in another file:

```
function testconnection(a, b, c, d)
{   alert('Test Function Hit.');
alert('Host: ' + a);
alert('Port: ' + b);
alert('User Name: ' + c);
alert('Password:' + d);
}
```

Am I even on the right track? Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you doing this via an AJAX request? If so, you'll need to respond with JSON data.

Comment: You're using [`sprintf()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) incorrectly. RTM for its proper usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems here, `sprintf` is used for variable substitution in strings, which is being done kind of oddly by passing in a string with variables as a parameter. You also aren't quoting your javascript variables, which will cause an error. Additionally, your function names aren't the same `testpbxconnection` vs. `testconnection`. Your `sprintf` call should look more like:

```
$submenu = sprintf('<div id="Menu">
       <ul id="ControlSubMenu">
         <li>
            <a href="#inner_content" class="TestConn" id="TestConn" onClick="testconnection(\'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\');return false;">Test Connection</a>
         </li>
         <li> 
            <a href="#inner_content" class="EditConn" id="EditConn" onClick="editpbxconnection();return false;">Edit Connection</a>
         </li>
       </ul>
     </div>', $ct_host, $ct_port, $ct_un, $ct_pw);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you should pass parameter as an argument while calling a function

    $demo = "Hello";
    <input type="text" onclick="return demoFunction(<?php echo $demo; ?> );"/>
    more references
    http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?147162-pass-php-variable-to-javascript-function
```